# Is it a good practice to use plain text for derivation of Keys?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis

I have a question regarding the derivation of keys in crypto.
Is it a good practice to use the plain text (in form of hashes) for derivation of keys ? these keys will be used for encryption of the same plain text later on.

What are possible drawbacks of the same if any ?

Thank You in advance.

**Edit 1**: For example

I have a plain text say *X*

The hash, *H = Random Text + X*;

Key, *K1 = Initial Key XOR H*;

Cipher *C = Enc (K1, X)*

So it is a good practice to use the plain text as shown in above manner for key generation and encryption ? 
what are the drawbacks of the same.

**Edit 2**
The other party will receive

Cipher *C* along with *C1 = Enc(K0, Hash)*

So that in order to decipher, apply *Dec(K0, C1) = Hash*

*K1 = Hash XOR K0*

and then *PT = Dec(K1, C)*

Thank You.

Comment: You mean `ciphertext = encrypt(hash(plaintext), plaintext)`? How do you decrypt `ciphertext`?

Comment: @yyyyyyy, My bad, I have updated the question to show the correct usage that I am thinking of.

Comment: OK, so now you have a Random Text, but it isn't clear how both parties know about the Random Text. Is it send together with the ciphertext?

Comment: Both parties would not have to know Random Text, only K1. You could imagine just one party generating the key and then exchanging it somehow. In fact if both parties generate the key they would need to know the message. Then you can ask why even encrypt? My guess is that you cannot really prove this secure according to standard definitions as key generation is usually assumed independent of the message.

Comment: @GuutBoy, I have updated the question. In this case, its not a one way encryption. Even if you know the plain text, the random text and hashing algorithm makes sure that the key is unpredictable. Also the hash is negotiated with other party along with cipher text in encrypted format. So that Other party can retrieve the hash and generate keys require to decrypt remaining blocks of cipher text. So does this key generation affect security in any means ? is it bad practice to do so ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `H = Hash(Random Text + X);`? You should clearly specify in your protocol: encryption, decryption, generation & features of data and what you send from one party to the other. Currently your protocol is still ill-defined.

Comment: My guess is, that you are trying to re-invent key encapsulation like it is done in hybrid encryption, without defining if you are using symmetric or asymmetric crypto. Right now there is no reason to "hash" the plaintext to derive a key. Comparing to choosing a random one, this only can introduce possible weaknesses without granting any benefit. Especially, since your notation does not actually indicate the use of a hash function, or a PBKDF - which would be necessary, if the plaintext is somehow predictable or easy to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash can only be calculated once you know the plaintext (and, in your case, the `Random Text` as well). If you already know the plaintext there is no need to know the key anymore.

So basically you have a scheme here that either offers no security at all, or a scheme that is impossible to decipher, even for the intended users (apart from guessing the plaintext).

---

In your update you show that you now *wrap* and *unwrap* the hash. That would make this scheme feasible, but it would still leak information. If you have identical plaintext then you will also have identical ciphertext, unles you change `Random Text` each time. You also haven't specified an IV.

---

If you have a random number generator already then it is much easier to calculate $K_d = KDF(K_{master}, Salt)$ and then $C = E(K_d, P)$. Or you could just use a random IV and (authenticated) encryption.

There is a strong feeling that you've deviced your own protocol because you are unfamiliar with common techniques. That's never a good idea.

Comment: I have updated the question. In this case, its not a one way encryption. Even if you know the plain text, the random text and hashing algorithm makes sure that the key is unpredictable. Also the hash is negotiated with other party along with cipher text in encrypted format. So that Other party can retrieve the hash and generate keys require to decrypt remaining blocks of cipher text. So does this key generation affect security in any means ? is it bad practice to do so ?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, the random text is IV. And it will be randomized every time it is used for hashing to make sure that hash algorithm doesn't collide. I do not use any predictable rng. IV is chosen from all possible IV space and added with P to generate collision free hash. And from hash the keys are generated. 
I don't think it is predictable by this way.